# Mpeg Dash html5 player or live video

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

simply put, I've been working at this problem and I can't seem to find a solution that works. I have been trying to locate a way to play live video from our Wowza server's MPEG dash streams with no luck. We're trying to stick to html5 's video tag since flash player doesn't work for our ARM based systems.

anyone have any clue on sources so I can actually get the foot in the door with this one? Feel like I've been charging at a brick wall all week.

Answer (score 1):

As Szatmary already mentioned MPEG-DASH using only the HTML video tag and feeding the .mpd to it won't work in web-browsers. However, you do not have to implement a player on your own, as there are solutions available which also support live scenarios, like [dash.js](http://dashif.org/reference/players/javascript/1.2.0/index.html) or [bitdash](http://www.dash-player.com/). For a playout with dash.js, MSE support in browsers is mandatory, whereas bitdash uses also a Flash fallback. Both are working on Chrome on Android and can handle live streams.

Answer (score 0):

the video tag will not work with DASH. Your browser needs to support Media Source Extensions (Many newer browsers do). Then each DASH segment needs to be downloaded and passed into MSE. DASH.js can do that for you. iOS does not support MSE. Nor does most android devices. for iOS you must use HLS in the `<video>` tag.

Comment: Ah, for android devices, is it down to the ARM infrastructure of simply no support as of yet? Additionally, thank-you, I was pretty clueless to what dash.js was for. Does it work with a live video stream?

Comment: Just support. I believe the latest android OS has it (not 100% sure). DASH has been very slow moving.